# Is it possible to opt your iPad app out of multitasking on iOS 9

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, ios9, multitasking

I have a large app that I will need some time to optimize for iOS9.

Edit: What I am worried about is all the UI getting squeezed together when the app window size is reduced. So my question is, is there any way to force full screen for the app?

Comment: I've made an edit to my answer. I also suggest you to watch the whole video from WWDC - it is very helpful in understanding the adoption process.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You have to modify your project to support multitasking. According to [WWDC 2015 video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=205), to adopt your app for multitasking, satisfy these requirements:

1. Build your app with iOS 9 SDK
2. Support all orientations
3. Use Launch Storyboards

So, if any of this is not done yet, your app will not be able to support multitasking.

Of course, if you don't use size classes, put it at the top of the list.

Edit: according to you question edit. There is a UIRequiresFullScreen key in Info.plist. See more at [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/AdoptingMultitaskingOniPad/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015145-CH3-SW1)

Comment: Missed that part. Thanks!

Comment: Great video and what a relief — by using UIRequiresFullScreen we can opt out. Multitasking makes little sense for my app and from a UI viewpoint I would have had to completely redesign it. So it's good to know you can opt out for the moment.

Comment: Also is storyboard mandatory? I am using xib in my project. Thanks!

Comment: Apple presentation says it's important, but no one said it's mandatory. But size classes are definitely a must thing to use these days.

Comment: Be sure to use "FullScreen" and not "Fullscreen".

Comment: Does "build your app with iOS 9 SDK" refer to the Base SDK setting, the iOS Deployment Target setting, or both?

Comment: Base SDK, you may use any deployment target you need

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't disable the Slide Over view. The user will have to disable that in settings.

Answer (score 202):

To opt-out (disable) multi-tasking for your application:

> **Select your Target** → **General Section** → Scroll Down and
>   check **Requires full screen**

It gets applied to the plist's `UIRequiresFullScreen` key value.

[image]

**Note:** Apps are required to support all screen orientations if it supports multitasking. Otherwise, apps will get the following error on publishing:

> Invalid Bundle. iPad Multitasking support requires these orientations: ...

Comment: I don't know, that option should be marked for legacy builds... Anyways... You saved my life! 5+ For you.

Comment: The key should be UIRequiresFullScreen, case sensitive (Source https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/AdoptingMultitaskingOniPad/QuickStartForSlideOverAndSplitView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015145-CH13-SW1)

Comment: @AlexSorokoletov please, go ahead and update the answer.

Comment: Doesn't let me edit 1 character. I see from the history you were able to change 1 character once.

Comment: How to disable multi-tasking for App-Extension ? because it steal autorotation control from my app.

Comment: With UIRequiresFullScreen solution, i can lock orientation on iPad2 & iPad Ratina. but it did not work on iPad Air  & iPad Pro.

Comment: This attribute shouldnt have any relation with the app supported orientation. As you can see in the same screen shots there are a seperate check box for the orientation. Also there is a combo box to switch between the iphone and ipad to allow the app to have a different set of upported orientation for each device class.

Comment: A tab bar and not combo box. The old xcode had a combo box.

Answer (score 22):

To opt out of Slide Over and Split View, do so explicitly by adding the `UIRequiresFullScreen` key to your Xcode project’s `Info.plist` file and apply the Boolean value `YES`.

You can set above thing using General tab of Targets, Select Requires Full Screen check. Refer below image for the same[image]

> **Note :**
>
> A user can disable Slide Over and Split View in Settings > General >
>   Multitasking. If you think you’ve set up everything correctly and find
>   that these features still don’t work, check this setting.

See [Adopting Multitasking Enhancements on iPad - Slide Over and Split View Quick Start](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/AdoptingMultitaskingOniPad/QuickStartForSlideOverAndSplitView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015145-CH13-SW1).

Answer (score 5):

It's still possible to opt-out of iPad multitasking — but Apple announced at WWDC 2019 that in **April 2020, all iPad apps will be required to support multitasking**.

The original announcement and discussion is in the [first few minutes of "Modernizing Your App for iOS 13"](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/224/), and there's a [(brief) announcement on their developer-news site](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=09242019a) as well.

Comment: Setting UIRequiresFullScreen to true in the info file still works

Comment: @thinklinux correct! But Apple's said that they will stop allowing this during App Store Review. I don't think they've started enforcing it yet, though!

Comment: Still seems like they’re not enforcing it. Even their own Final Cut Pro doesn’t support multitasking.