# Disable dock (quick launch bar) feature on IOS 11 for ipad

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, dock

Recently, IOS 11 for ipad provides a dock (quick launch bar) for applications switching. It supports multitasking and allows to switch to an application from dock with drag and drop function even another foreground application is running. The newly switched application will be located in split view on top of the foreground application. Therefore, multi applications are running in the foreground without closed the original foreground application.

[image]

Since our application is confidential and high security, It is prohibited to copy the contents to other applications. Some codes have been implemented and executed to erase the copied texts when the application is switch from foreground execution to background execution. It works fine in previous IOS version because user must return to home screen by press the home button (in this case the foreground application will switch to background) first and then select another application.

So my question is:

1. Without disable the multitasking in setting, is that any other methods to hide or disable the dock feature on IOS 11?
2. Is that any objective-c class that application can trigger the dock execution? (erase the copied text when dock menu is shown)?

Comment: I think your only option is to opt your app out of multitasking; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30765157/is-it-possible-to-opt-your-ipad-app-out-of-multitasking-on-ios-9

Comment: @Paulw11 thanks. i will try it and tell you the result.

Comment: @Paulw11 tried. but it not work.

Comment: Do you want to allow copy/paste within your app?  If not then you could simply clear the pasteboard as soon as anything was pasted to it. Your app should get a `willResignActive` delegate call when the new app becomes active.

Comment: @Paulw11 the willResignActive is triggered only when start the dock. if two applications are running in the foreground and then copy the text from primary application to secondary application, the willResignActive did not 
 trigger.

Comment: Then you are probably out of luck unless you can afford to lose copy/paste within your app.  If this is an enterprise app then you can distribute it via MDM as a managed app which will prevent copy/paste to non-managed apps, otherwise unless you can stop people taking a photo of the iPad screen trying to prevent information leakage is kind of pointless anyway