# Is there a way to get rid of Multitasking Menu Bar for iPadOS 15?

Tags: flutter, dart, ipad, ipados15

The three dots at the top of the screen interferes with my UI. Is there a way to hide/disable this?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Xcode screenshot]

[This person answered my question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31771093/14307385)