# How to exactly replicate native Camera.app UI?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, camera, avfoundation

I'm currently implementing a custom camera app, and it turns out that replicating Camera.app's UI is quite tricky!

The question that bothers me the most is of course autorotation. Camera.app creates an illusion that UI doesn't rotate, except for some buttons, but it does rotate! This is clear, because:

- Home indicator also rotates with the device
- Control Center and Notification Center can be pulled down from the top

According to [this Q&A](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1890/_index.html), looks like Camera.app uses `viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator)`, and rotates the elements in opposite direction to create the illusion that nothing actually rotates. But there's a catch: to achieve this effect, views should not use Auto Layout, which makes lots of things more complicated than needed.
Using sample code from the aforementioned Q&A I created a simple app that uses a UIImageView with a screenshot of the Camera.app.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let imageView = UIImageView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(imageView)
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "camera_screenshot.PNG")
    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        imageView.frame = view.bounds
    }
    
    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
        self.imageView.center = CGPoint(x: self.view.bounds.midX, y: self.view.bounds.midY)
    }
    
    
    override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
        
        coordinator.animate { context in
            let deltaTransform = coordinator.targetTransform
            let deltaAngle = atan2(deltaTransform.b, deltaTransform.a)
    
            if let currentRotation = self.imageView.layer.value(forKeyPath: "transform.rotation.z") as? CGFloat {
                let newRotation = currentRotation + (-1 * deltaAngle + 0.0001)
                self.imageView.layer.setValue(newRotation, forKeyPath: "transform.rotation.z")
            }
        } completion: { context in
            // Integralize the transform to undo the extra 0.0001 added to the rotation angle.
            var currentTransform = self.imageView.transform
            currentTransform.a = round(currentTransform.a)
            currentTransform.b = round(currentTransform.b)
            currentTransform.c = round(currentTransform.c)
            currentTransform.d = round(currentTransform.d)
            self.imageView.transform = currentTransform
        }
    }
    
    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

Good! But not good enough! [As you can see in this video](https://i.imgur.com/LSmrmOa.mp4) the image view doesn't rotate but there's still system animation of rotating the UIWindow (I guess?). Interestingly enough, this system animation appears on iPhone 7 (iOS 13.4.1), but doesn't appear on iPhone 11 Pro (iOS 14.3).

So my questions are:

- How to get rid of that "system animation"?
- Is it possible to replicate Camera.app UI **WITH** Auto Layout?

Note: please, do not suggest [the approach with multiple UIWindow's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28796685/4934534) because it feels quite hacky to me.

Comment: If anyone knows developers of Halide app, please send them this post. Halide handles autorotation perfectly!

Comment: This is one of the devs: https://stackoverflow.com/users/1625080/ben-sandofsky

Comment: Wish I could tag him here (( It's a shame that SO doesn't support tagging users directly

Comment: You could try pinging them on twitter.